# Android: How to tell if a user presses up, down, left or right?

Tags: java, android

I created an onTouchEvent to find where the user touches and move my object to that position. what I would like to do is if the user presses up on the screen, the object moves a certain distance straight up. and the same for the other directions. I know that I need a few if statements to do this but I don't know how to do it. does anyone have any advice or know how to do this, thanks

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {

    if(ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        // the new image position became where you touched
        x = ev.getX();
        y = ev.getY();


    // if statement to detect where user presses down        
    if(){
    }
        // redraw the image at the new position
        Draw.this.invalidate();
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {

    initialise boolean actionDownFlag = false;

    if(ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        // the new image position became where you touched
        x = (int) ev.getX();
        y = (int) ev.getY();


    // if statement to detect where user presses down        
    if(actionDownFlag){

        catcher.moveDown();
    }
        // redraw the image at the new position
        Draw.this.invalidate();
    }
    return true;
}

    public void moveDown(){

        posX -= //WhereEver you want to move the position (-5);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
layout_counter.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event)
    {
        if (currentState != State.EDIT_MOVE) return false;

        FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
        if (view.getId() != R.id.layout_counter) return false;

        switch (event.getAction())
        {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                params.topMargin = (int) event.getRawY() - view.getHeight();
                params.leftMargin = (int) event.getRawX() - (view.getWidth() / 2);
                view.setLayoutParams(params);
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                params.topMargin = (int) event.getRawY() - view.getHeight();
                params.leftMargin = (int) event.getRawX() - (view.getWidth() / 2);
                view.setLayoutParams(params);
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                view.setLayoutParams(params);
                break;
        }

        return true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `OnLongClickListener` which suits better with drag and drop framework of android:

Observe the following example:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private ImageView myImage;
    private static final String IMAGEVIEW_TAG = "The Android Logo";

/** Called when the activity is first created. */

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        myImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
         // Sets the tag
        myImage.setTag(IMAGEVIEW_TAG);

        // set the listener to the dragging data
        myImage.setOnLongClickListener(new MyClickListener());

        findViewById(R.id.toplinear).setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());
        findViewById(R.id.bottomlinear).setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());

    }

    private final class MyClickListener implements OnLongClickListener {

        // called when the item is long-clicked
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            // create it from the object's tag
            ClipData.Item item = new ClipData.Item((CharSequence)view.getTag());

            String[] mimeTypes = { ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN };
            ClipData data = new ClipData(view.getTag().toString(), mimeTypes, item);
            DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(view);

            view.startDrag( data, //data to be dragged
                            shadowBuilder, //drag shadow
                            view, //local data about the drag and drop operation
                            0   //no needed flags
                          );


            view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            return true;
        }  
    }

    class MyDragListener implements OnDragListener {
        Drawable normalShape = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.normal_shape);
        Drawable targetShape = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.target_shape);

        @Override
        public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {

            // Handles each of the expected events
            switch (event.getAction()) {

            //signal for the start of a drag and drop operation.
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
                // do nothing
                break;

            //the drag point has entered the bounding box of the View
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
                v.setBackground(targetShape);   //change the shape of the view
                break;

            //the user has moved the drag shadow outside the bounding box of the View
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
                v.setBackground(normalShape);   //change the shape of the view back to normal
                break;

            //drag shadow has been released,the drag point is within the bounding box of the View
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                // if the view is the bottomlinear, we accept the drag item
                  if(v == findViewById(R.id.bottomlinear)) {
                      View view = (View) event.getLocalState();
                      ViewGroup viewgroup = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
                      viewgroup.removeView(view);

                      //change the text
                      TextView text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text);
                      text.setText("The item is dropped");

                      LinearLayout containView = (LinearLayout) v;
                      containView.addView(view);
                      view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                  } else {
                      View view = (View) event.getLocalState();
                      view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                      Context context = getApplicationContext();
                      Toast.makeText(context, "You can't drop the image here",
                                                 Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                      break;
                   }
                  break;

            //the drag and drop operation has concluded.
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
                v.setBackground(normalShape);   //go back to normal shape

            default:
                break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

The above code taken from [here](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/ui/drag-and-drop/android-drag-and-drop-example/) demonstrates how to drag and drop and how to do something while dragging..
I've used something similar as well.